# Cannot run addEventListener (resize) in VueJS CLI to get screen width

Tags: vue.js, resize, addeventlistener, event-listener

I want to generate two html code for two different screen size in VueJS. I tried to use addEventListener in order to get the screen width constantly and I am stuck. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
export default{

    data() {
        return {
            currentWidth: 0,
            desktopView: true
        }
    },        

    methods:{
         detectScreenWidth(event){
             this.currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
             console.log("currentWidth: "+this.currentWidth);
         }
    },

    created() {
        document.addEventListener('resize', this.detectScreenWidth );
    },

    beforeDestroy() {
        document.removeEventListener('resize', this.detectScreenWidth);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `window.document` in the `created()` life-cycle hook because the Vue instance is not mounted in the DOM yet. This can be done in `mounted()`.

Comment: I have tried to use mounted and it does not work as well. I cannot get this.currentWidth constantly when I do resize. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event:

> However, resize events are only fired on the window object

which means you should call

```
window.addEventListener('resize', this.detectScreenWidth );
```

instead of `document`.

Also, as Nikolay Yankov mentioned you should call `addEventListener` within `mounted()` method. The resulting code:

```
mounted(){
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.detectScreenWidth );
}
```